# c++ (g++-4.x) problem with templates

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have this simple code:

```
template<template <class> class Generator>
class TestHelper {};

template<class Writer>
class Test
{
    typedef TestHelper< Test >  Helper;  
};
```

It's works great on last g++ versions, but, in 4.4 or 4.5, I get this error:

```
test.cpp:7: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class Generator> class TestHelper' 
test.cpp:7: error:   expected a class template, got 'Test<Writer>'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It seems strange that inside a template you define `Helper` to be the instantiation of a different template with your own template as a template argument... Are you sure that you don't want `TestHelper` to take `Test<Writer>`  (instantiation) and not `Test` (template) as argument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because inside the body of class `Test<Writer>`, naming `Test` without providing the template arguments automatically assumes the same arguments (e.g. `Writer`).

For example, this allows you to write the copy constructor as:

```
Test(const Test&);
```

instead of

```
Test::Test(const Test<Writer>&);
```

You can overcome this by qualifying `Test` with its namespace, e.g.

```
 typedef TestHelper< ::Test >  Helper;
```

---

NOTE: As Tomalek suggests, the original usage is valid in C++0x.  Here is the relevant paragraph of the standard (emphasis mine), from section 14.6.1 (`[temp.local]`):

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9).  The injected-class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*. **When it is used** with a *template-argument-list*, **as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter***, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, **it refers to the class template itself**. Otherwise, it is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in <>.

Comment: I bet that using a qualified name as in `my_namespace::Test`, or `::Test` solves it.

Comment: @David: Just discovered that while playing around in Comeau Try-it-out.  After trying `typename` and `template` (both fail).

Comment: Thanks both! I didn't know that. Seems weird that in g++ 4.5 works, isn't that?

Comment: @Hugo: The rules changed in C++0x, IIRC?

Comment: @Tomalek: You appear to be correct, in any case, the bare name is permissible under C++0x.

Answer (score 1):

@Ben is probably right, but here's a totally different way to get it to compile, that doesn't use templates as args to templates.

```
template<class Generator> // changed this to a simpler template
class TestHelper {};

template<class Writer>
class Test
{
            typedef TestHelper< typename Test :: Writer >  Helper; // 2nd change
};
```

I made two changes. @Hugo, maybe this is what you wanted, and maybe this is what older versions of g++ did?

It's easy to get code to compile, but that doesn't mean that it does what you think it does!

Comment: When you have template template parameters, you normally have a reason to do so.

Comment: @Xeo: Bad code is often used under the belief there is a valid reason to do so.  There's more to consider than "I think I need to do this" ("I have a reason to do this"), and template-template parameters should usually be replaced.